# Repeater Footer Total

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I'm a bit stumped as to why this isn't working, I may be doing something wrong.

I have a repeater with values in the Amount column, I want to show the total of this column in the footer of the repeater.

The problem is that the Total is always showing 0 and not adding the values of the rows up.

**CODE BEHIND**

```
Protected Sub reCosts_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles reCosts.ItemDataBound

        Dim rowView As System.Data.DataRowView
        rowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView)

        Dim CostsTotal As Decimal

        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then


            Dim lCostAmount As Literal = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lCostAmount"), Literal)
            Dim CostAmount As Decimal = rowView("Amount")
            lCostAmount.Text = CostAmount.ToString("C2")


            CostsTotal += CostAmount


        ElseIf e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer Then

            Dim lCostsTotal As Literal = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lCostsTotal"), Literal)
            lCostsTotal.Text = CostsTotal.ToString("C2")

        End If

    End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

J.

Comment: Why are you casting `CostAmount` to a `String` if you're adding it to another `Decimal`?

Comment: That is just for formatting as a currency. Although i was casting as a `string` when adding to the `CostTotal` which i have removed, but didn't sort the problem

Comment: Have you debugged? I'd imagine it could be hitting the footer listitemtype first, then going into the others and doing the addition. So you'll always get zero. Test this by using a session object instead, after databinding, set the lCostsTotal to the value in the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is the `CostsTotal` variable is being declared each time an item is bound and resetting to zero when it is binding the footer.

You need to add a property that is saved in ViewState like this:

```
Public Property [CostsTotal] As String
   Get
       Return CStr(ViewState("CostsTotal"))
   End Get
   Set
       ViewState("CostsTotal") = Value
   End Set
End Property
```

Also make sure you remove this line:

```
Dim CostsTotal As Decimal
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure what this does but it worked, will research into it a bit more.

Comment: No worries, nice one. I'll try and explain. The new view state property gets set and updated when each row (data item or record) is bound. You then display this value when the footer is bound.

Answer (score 1):

[@hutchonoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595786/repeater-footer-total?noredirect=1#17596275) is right.  Problem is `CostsTotal` is being set to 0 on each time an item is bound.  However, you shouldn't put it in viewstate.  If it's in viewstate, then `CostsTotal += CostsTotal` will occur on every postback since it's being persisted.

Move `Dim CostsTotal As Decimal` to the top of your page so it starts at `0` on every postback.